# How to create a loop that checks if a value is greater than AND stays greater than some number for a certain # of days?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

First and foremost, thank you for taking your time to view my question.

My question is regarding a flag that I am trying to create:
Essentially the flag works like this:
- If the value of column vals is greater than 3 for 3 consecutive days, I want the original value to be flagged. I am trying to use an ifelse statement, however, I just don't know how to code the "stays greater than 3 for 3 consecutive days" in R. I have tried for multiple hours without no solution :/

The sample data might looks something like this

```
Date      Vals
8/1/11     2.5
8/2/11     2.6
8/3/11     1.6
8/4/11     3.6
8/5/11     3.5
8/6/11     3.1
8/7/11     3.8
8/8/11     2.1
8/9/11     1.6
8/10/11    3.1
```

So essentially: I would get a third column called FLAG that would only list error on 8/4/11 and 8/5/11 column and NO ERROR on the rest.

Please let me know, and thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(zoo)
df$FLAG <- rollapply(na.fill(df$Vals, 0), 3, 
                     function(x) if(all(x > 3)) 'ERROR' 
                                 else 'NO ERROR'
                     , fill = 'NO ERROR'
                     , align = 'left')

df
#        Date Vals     FLAG
#  1:  8/1/11  2.5 NO ERROR
#  2:  8/2/11  2.6 NO ERROR
#  3:  8/3/11  1.6 NO ERROR
#  4:  8/4/11  3.6    ERROR
#  5:  8/5/11  3.5    ERROR
#  6:  8/6/11  3.1 NO ERROR
#  7:  8/7/11  3.8 NO ERROR
#  8:  8/8/11  2.1 NO ERROR
#  9:  8/9/11  1.6 NO ERROR
# 10: 8/10/11  3.1 NO ERROR
```

Data used:

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread("
Date      Vals
8/1/11     2.5
8/2/11     2.6
8/3/11     1.6
8/4/11     3.6
8/5/11     3.5
8/6/11     3.1
8/7/11     3.8
8/8/11     2.1
8/9/11     1.6
8/10/11    3.1
")
```

Comment: Hi Ryan. Thanks for the answer. However - I am getting an error: "Evaluation Error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" this might be due to some NA's I have. any ways to bypass that? Thanks

Comment: See my edit. I used `na.fill` to replace the `NA` values with `0` within the function, which should fix the issue. The actual values in the data.frame will remain `NA`.

Comment: Hi Ryan. just fixed it. Thanks for your input. it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Flag=ifelse(Vals >=3, 1, 0)) %>% group_by(Flag) %>%
       mutate(Flag_final=ifelse(lead(Flag, n=3)==1, 'ERROR', 'No ERROR')) %>% #Check if the 3rd value from the current value is equal to 1 "Using dplyr::lead" 
       ungroup() %>% select(-Flag) %>%  
       mutate(Flag_final=ifelse(is.na(Flag_final),'No ERROR',Flag_final)) 


# A tibble: 10 x 3
  Date     Vals Flag_final
  <fct>   <dbl> <chr>     
  1 8/1/11    2.5 No ERROR  
  2 8/2/11    2.6 No ERROR  
  3 8/3/11    1.6 No ERROR  
  4 8/4/11    3.6 ERROR     
  5 8/5/11    3.5 ERROR     
  6 8/6/11    3.1 No ERROR  
  7 8/7/11    3.8 No ERROR  
  8 8/8/11    2.1 No ERROR  
  9 8/9/11    1.6 No ERROR  
 10 8/10/11   3.1 No ERROR
```

## data

```
df<-read.table(text="
           Date      Vals
           8/1/11     2.5
           8/2/11     2.6
           8/3/11     1.6
           8/4/11     3.6
           8/5/11     3.5
           8/6/11     3.1
           8/7/11     3.8
           8/8/11     2.1
           8/9/11     1.6
           8/10/11    3.1
           ",header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one shot with `mutate` and `lead`:

```
library(dplyr)
f1 %>% mutate(FLAG = ifelse(Vals > 3 &
                            lead(Vals) > 3 &
                            lead(Vals, 2) > 3)
                            , 'ERROR', 'NO ERROR'))`
```

If you want the last two entries always to be "NO ERROR" (even if they could be the start of a 3-day streak), you can force the issue:

```
library(dplyr)
f1 %>% mutate(FLAG = ifelse(Vals > 3 &
                            lead(Vals) > 3 &
                            lead(Vals, 2) > 3 &
                            !is.na(lead(Vals)) &
                            !is.na(lead(Vals, 2))
                            , 'ERROR', 'NO ERROR'))`
```